# Select box option add works in IE but not Firefox

Tags: firefox, select

In Firefox the `"alert("backupopt2="+backupopt);"` does not execute i.e. there appears to be a problem with `"backupelement.add(backupopt);"`.  Nothing on the Java console.  Assistance appreciated; thanks.

```
for(i = 0; i < backupresponsesplit.length; i++)
       {
         var backupopt = document.createElement("OPTION");
         var backupelement = document.getElementById("metarecords");
         backupopt.text = backupresponsesplit[i];
         backupopt.value = backupresponsesplit[i];
         alert("backupopt1="+backupopt);
         backupelement.add(backupopt);
         alert("backupopt2="+backupopt); 
       }

<select size="3" id="metarecords" style="width:845; height:54; font-family:monospace" onChange="ajaxMeta();">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming metarecords id belongs to a select tag
instead of 'add' try this

```
backupelement.appendChild(backupopt);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Adithya, that did it.  It then stopped working in IE, but I came across backupopt.innerHTML = backupresponsesplit[i]; to replace backupopt.text = backupresponsesplit[i];.  Now working in both browsers.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great!, accept the answer if it worked, that way question wont remain open